# preg_match_all, then remove duplicate when loop using php

Tags: php, for-loop, preg-match-all, duplicates

Although there are many similar questions and answers here and i've tried my best to make it work but no luck. This is my code:

```
$content = "Blah...blah...[image=1], 
            blah...blah...blah...[image=2],
            blah...blah...blah...[image=1], no more...";

function get_image($content) 
{ 
  $stripper = $content;   
  preg_match_all("/\[image=(.+?)\]/smi",$stripper, $search);
  $total = count($search[0]);    
    for($i=0; $i < $total; $i++) 
    {    
      $image_id = $search[1][$i];
      if($image_id > 0)
      {
        $image = 'This is an image: <img src="images/'.$image_id.'.jpg" />';
      }
      $stripper = str_replace($search[0][$i], $image, $stripper); 
    } 
  return $stripper; 
}
```

I want to remove the duplicate "[image=1]" and return:

```
Blah...blah...This is an image: <image>, 
blah...blah...blah...This is an image: <image>, 
blah...blah...blah..., no more...
```

or

```
Blah...blah..., 
blah...blah...blah...This is an image: <image>, 
blah...blah...blah...This is an image: <image>, no more...
```

Comment: so.. use array_unique before you loop.

Comment: Better yet `preg_replace_callback` than having a secondary `str_replace()`. Use a state variable and `in_array()` to skip previous values.

Comment: @AD7six I tried: $total = count(array_unique$search[0])); but not working.

Comment: @mario How? Can you point me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the manual on [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback).

Use a state variable to skip previous values like this:

```
  $content = preg_replace_callback(
      "/\[image=(.+?)\]/smi",
      function ($m) {
          global $skip_images;
          $image = $m[1];
          if ( !isset($skip_images[$image]) ) {
              $skip_images[$image] = 1;
              return "<img src=$image.jpeg>";
          }
      },
      $content
  );
```

Obviously the $skip_images code could be writen nicer; use a closure state variable, or must be cleared if you use that callback another place or time.